# Could Yao's Millionaires' problem be used as a problem of binary search?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, searchable-encryption

I recently started reading about Yao's Millionaires' problem. If the Yao's Millionaires' problem is capable of finding if one party has less money / more or equal money than the other party, then is it possible for one party to find the exact amount of money that the other party have?

I specifically read the articles posted by Professor Bill Buchanan:

- https://asecuritysite.com/rsa/mill2
- https://asecuritysite.com/zero/mill

Where as we can see the two parties that communicate with each other share a computed value (which is not the amount of money the have) and with the algorithm we are capable of finding out who has more money. As stated by Professor Bill : "In Millionaire's Problem, we can determine which of two millionaires has the most money, without them actually giving away the amount of money they have".

Now, let's move this problem to a program concept. Imagine a server that has a hardcoded value and accepts amounts from clients. Based on the Yao's Millionaires' problem, it responds to the users if their value is less than the servers (client_value < server_value) or if its greater or equal to the value that the server has (client_value >= server_value).
Is it possible with some way for a client to find the exact value that the server have? (for example using binary search....?) And if its possible, then how?
Remember that the clients and the server **do not exchange their real values**, but a value like Professor Buchanan showcases.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the way it is normally stated, the two users A and B interact with a trusted server, behave according to the protocol and at the end learn which one has more money, let's say weather $w(A)\geq w(B),$ where $w$ is the wealth.

So your setup of the problem needs to be changed to $B$ being *another* trusted server with a fixed stored value $w(S')=w_0.$ If $A,S'$ behave according to a protocol that solves the millionaire's problem then indeed $A$ can learn if $w(A) \geq w(S').$

*Binary search*  for $w$ (simple range, otherwise go to the next power of 2 and run this): If I have a range $[1,2^3]$ then I ask if $w \leq 2^2$ if yes split this interval into two and ask if $w \leq 2^1,$ etc. Split left if I keep getting yes otherwise split right.

Say $w=3$: Is $w\leq 2^2$? Yes; Is $w \leq 2^1$? No; So we know $w$ is in $[2^1+1,2^2]=[3,4]$. Then just query if $w \leq 3$ and you get the answer.

Use binary search in the following way, if you like start conservatively and let $w_1=\textrm{floor}[w(\textrm{Musk})/2].$ I put the queries to the Yao server as if statements.

So you can query if $w_0$ is in range $[1,w_1].$ If no, ask if $w_0$ is in the range $[w_1+1,2w_1]=[w_1+1,w(\textrm{Musk})].$ Otherwise continue binary search technique on $[1,w_1]$ splitting to the left half.

Comment: Thank you for the response:) But I think what you say is that the two parties share their actual amount of money the have, while in the Yao's Millionaire problem they share a computed value that contained the digits that their value have and based on that you can determine if someone has more or equal / less money than the other. See here : 1) https://asecuritysite.com/zero/mill    , 2) https://asecuritysite.com/rsa/mill2. Based on these two articles from Mr. Bill , I would like to somehow apply binary search on shared values , where shared values are not the actual amount of money.

Comment: your question is not properly stated then. I only use the Yao algorithm as a black box. I interpreted your question not two person but as one person trying to find out the stored secret income value. Please fix your question

Comment: @kodlue Im sorry if my question was not clear:/ Could you kindly review my edited question and let me know of your thoughts about the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I understood correctly, it is exactly what kodlu answered already.